# Error in two "when then" in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep getting an error in this SQL Server statement:

```
select 
    (CASE WHEN (date_join < DATEADD(year,-10,GETDATE())) 
            THEN '11 years or more'
          WHEN date_join > (DATEADD(year,-10,GETDATE())) 
            THEN '10 years or less'
     END) as eee,
    COUNT(agency_code) as yr_num
from 
    agency_fulllist
group by 
    eee
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Year is a reserved word in ANSI SQL, delimit it as `"year"`.

Comment: Remove redundant parentheses, and it will be easier to read and find such problems.

Comment: Does MS SQL Server support group by column alias? (Non-ANSI functionality.)

Comment: _What_ error do you get?? No, @Jarlh, "invalid column name 'eee'"

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `case` expression part up in a derived table, then do `GROUP BY` on it's result:

```
select eee, COUNT(agency_code) as yr_num
(
select CASE WHEN date_join < DATEADD(year,-10,GETDATE()) THEN '11 years or more'
            WHEN date_join > DATEADD(year,-10,GETDATE()) THEN '10 years or less'
       END as eee,
       agency_code
from agency_fulllist
) dt
group by eee
```

**Note:** `year` is a reserved word in ANSI SQL. You may need to delimit it as `"year"`.

Comment: Additionally you can also replace the 2nd `WHEN` with `ELSE`.

Comment: @dnoeth, almost the same, consider NULL's, and equal.

Comment: Yep, at least equality should have a very low probability :-)

Comment: I have tried all suggestions above but all have error, even after I change the codes and hope it works.

Comment: I finally solved this by push "select case when" in a view, then use that view to group.

Comment: A derived table is pretty much the same as a one-time view.